# Why does the CIS benchmark consider the presence of passwd- a (high) risk

Tags: linux, password-management, cis-framework

I've just seen a "high-risk security alert" for the presence of `/etc/passwd-` (note the trailing '-') on RHEL 8 servers, and don't understand the issue. Apparently the issue originates with the CIS benchmarks.

My understanding is that it's a backup of the passwd file created by utilities like `adduser`; what I don't understand is the security implication of having a backup of the file with the same permissions as the original. Given that `/etc/passwd` is always world-readable anyway (presumably so that ls can convert a UID in an inode to a username amongst other reasons), what's the risk?

I guess a hacker (who is already on the box as a non-privileged user) could diff the files to see the most recent change, but I can't see what else constitutes a "risk". Is this one of those issues raised by not-too-smart security tools? "Oh, a world-readable file in /etc - panic"? What am I missing? Googling doesn't distinguish `/etc/passwd-` from `/etc/passwd`, so I've not managed to find anything relevant elsewhere.

I guess there's no harm in removing it - well except that it is a forensic clue perhaps, that one of the os tools was used to modify user information, which is pretty spurious, really.

Comment: Security scanners worth their salt won't just say that something is a risk - their output will include details on why. What exactly did your scanner say about it?

Comment: This seemed like an easy question to answer; but I've been digging for 20 mins in man pages and the CIS Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8 Benchmark v1.0.1, and I am no closer to having an answer for you. `/etc/passwd` is intended to be world-readable by design, so who cares if there's a copy if it lying around?

Comment: @graham we need to actual and full output to rule out a misinterpretation. CIS benchmarks talk about permissions on that file, not the existence of it. https://www.cisecurity.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/CIS_Oracle_Linux_6_Benchmark_v1.0.0.pdf pg 261

Comment: @schroeder I think you found the answer. Can you re-open this question so I can answer it? Answer seems to be that CIS Benchmarks (at least the Oracle Linux 6 version you're quoting) knows about the `/etc/passwd-` file, and wants its permissions to be `chmod 600`, which is different from the `644` on `/etc/passwd`.

Comment: @MikeOunsworth but that's not what the OP asked. And that's why I'm asking for clarification. If the link is the answer, I found that in less than 60 seconds of Googling a single query (CIS benchmark "passwd-"). Which means this is a poor question (and easily looked up once the OP doesn't reframe what the finding was). Questions that can be answered with a single link that is easily googled should be answered in comments.

Comment: @schroeder ... yeah, alright. I guess that's why you have the diamond after your name cause you're willing to make decisions like this.

Comment: @MikeOunsworth we can't be a replacement for Google. If the answer can be found in under 60s on Google, we aren't providing value. But let's see what the finding actually says.

Comment: I did google, and found problems distinguishing between passwd, and passwd- .  I eventually (CIS took a _long_ time emailing me the d/l link) got the pdf; realised that security had misunderstood, and decided that the existence of the file was an issue.   I still don't understand why a) it should be 0600, rather than 0644, and b) why there is any "risk" in the first place.  Who decides that it's a risk (+ that this risk is greater than that of not having a backup - which is small)?  Is CIS not useful, or should our security people be more discerning?  Rm'ing the file is daft - it'll reappear.

Comment: Is it worth asking a question as to why the different modes for passwd and passwd- ?

Comment: You can download the CIS benchmarks PDFs from their website, no need to email them

Comment: @johndoe You can't, and I didn't.  When you try to download there's an infowall which demands details and an email address, to which a link is sent, from where you can download.  That process took half a day.

Comment: @GrahamNicholls ahh I see, yes depending on how their emails acts it could take a long time, someone should really set up a site with a mirror to all their PDFs so we don't have to leak info to a random website to download security benchmarks. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: Hey @johndoe no worries, and sorry for sounding so combative. I did look for a mirror - but wanted to go to the source for a few reasons.    As for the recommendation from CIS, there's a couple of questions: 1) why 0600, rather than 0640 as the original, and 2) WTH, anyway - I could simply rename passwd- to ".i_am_spartacus", and the metric would be met - seems entirely specious?